# SSRS 2012 with SQL2005 Databases

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

The following article states that SSRS 2016 supports SQL2008 and beyond for its ReportingServer DB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/ssrs-report-server-create-a-report-server-database

However, I couldn't find any article specifying the supported database versions for SSRS 2012 - Does anyone know if running SSRS 2012 is supported with a SQL2005 database?

Many thanks,

Paul

Comment: I would lean to saying yes, but I don' t have a SQL Server 2005 db to test it with.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question and might be better posted on https://dba.stackexchange.com/